# how can i get object key with distinct values from array of objects in elasticsearch using aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

i have products collection(index) with following documents :

```
{ name : 'test1',
   attributes : [ {name :"color" , value : 'red'}, {name  : 'size' , value : 's'}, {name  : 'type' , value : 'simple'}]
}

{ name : 'test2',
    attributes : [{name  : 'size' , value : 'm'}]
}

{ name : 'test3',
    attributes : [ {name :"color" , value : 'green'},  {name  : 'size' , value : 's'}]
}

{ name : 'test4',
    attributes : [ {name :"color" , value : 'red'}]
}
```

How can i get output like below using elastic search aggregation ? 
Output :

```
{
    attributes : {
        color : [ {value : 'red', count : 2}, {value : 'green', count : 1} ],
        size : [ { value : 's', count : 2}, {value : 'm', count : 1}],
        type : [ {value : 'simple', count : 1}]
    }

}
```